# How can a domain name be registered and showing content but not have any DNS or nameserver entries?

Tags: dns, domain-name, nameserver, whois, registrar

I have done a whois lookup on theinsuranceemporium.co.uk but even though it outputs a test page at local.theinsuranceemporium.co.uk and a whois lookup shows the registering party, there are no DNS or nameserver records showing as related to the domain name. Can anyone explain to me how this can be or point me towards a resource which might be useful explaining the related concepts to a lowly Web Developer :).

Comment: Huh? `nslookup theinsuranceemporium.co.uk` returns Addresses:  64:ff9b::54f:24af
          5.79.36.175

Comment: Oh. I just went to http://who.is/dns/theinsuranceemporium.co.uk

Comment: https://whois.domaintools.com/theinsuranceemporium.co.uk: Name servers:
        dns1.stabletransit.com
        dns2.stabletransit.com

Comment: Use a more reliable whois ;)

Comment: Thanks David. The ip info was very good for satiating my curiosity regarding their unusual system setup! Learning new things all the time! :D

Comment: Their dns setup is broken according to http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/theinsuranceemporium.co.uk/

Comment: It certainly had some unusual symbolic link stuff going on in their Apache setup when I last looked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There are no DNS or nameserver records showing as related to the domain name

You are using an unreliable whois server.

```
F:\test>nslookup theinsuranceemporium.co.uk
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.42.129

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    theinsuranceemporium.co.uk
Addresses:  64:ff9b::54f:24af
          5.79.36.175
```

I normally use http://www.domaintools.com/:

```
Name servers:
    dns1.stabletransit.com
    dns2.stabletransit.com
```

Full record:

```
Domain name:
        theinsuranceemporium.co.uk

    Registrant:
        The Equine & Livestock Insurance Company Limited

    Trading as: 
        The Equine & Livestock Insurance Company Limited

    Registrant type:
        UK Limited Company, (Company number: 294940)

    Registrant's address:
        Equine & Livestock Insurance Company LTD
        Thorpe Underwood Hall Great Ouseburn
        York
        York
        YO269SS
        United Kingdom

    Data validation:
        Nominet was not able to match the registrant's name and/or address against a 3rd party 
source on 15-Jan-2016

    Registrar:
        1api GmbH [Tag = 1API-DE]
        URL: http://www.1api.net

    Relevant dates:
        Registered on: 24-Oct-2014
        Expiry date:  24-Oct-2016
        Last updated:  15-Jan-2016

    Registration status:
        Registered until expiry date.

    Name servers:
        dns1.stabletransit.com
        dns2.stabletransit.com

Disclaimer
WHOIS lookup made at 19:35:50 27-Mar-2016
```

Source https://whois.domaintools.com/theinsuranceemporium.co.uk

Comment: Hmmmm, they seem to be using both The Equine & Livestock Insurance Company Limited and Equine & Livestock Insurance Company LTD. Clerical error perhaps ;).